# Не отправляется почта в Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii, ubuntu

День добрый!

Конфиг вот такой вот:

```
   'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',

        'useFileTransport' => false,

        ],
```

Но почта не уходит, стандартная функция php mail работает. Подскажите, что делать, куда копать?

OS Ubuntu v14

Comment: Укажите операционную систему

Comment: OS Ubuntu v14

Comment: посмотрите [здесь][1]
[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в настройках сервера, нужно смотреть, в логах что происходит при отправке письма `tail -f /var/log/syslog`.

Лучше используй SMTP сервер, так больше вероятности, что твое письмо не улетит в SPAM:

```
'mailer' => [
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'messageConfig' => [
        'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    ],
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.google.com',
        'username' => 'your_email@gmail.com',
        'password' => '*********',
        'port' => '465',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Проблема в php safe_mode.   
В настройках php.ini safe_mode=Off но функция mail не хочет работать с передачей пятого параметра.  
Php версии 5.5.9

Вот что в доках php:  
Параметр additional_parameters отключен в режиме safe_mode и при его использовании функция mail() вызовет предупреждение и вернет FALSE.

За совет SMTP сервер спасибо, но хочется разобраться, в чем тут дело, если есть идеи, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь 'streamOptions' в config где почта настраивается. Должно получиться что-то вроде такого:

```
return [
  'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
      'transport' => [
        'streamOptions' => [ 
          'ssl' => [ 
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```